# Commercial vs private financial gain

Tags: formal-language, ielts

While prepping for IELTS academic reading, I've encountered the following passage:

> The penalties for breaching the copyright act differ slightly
> depending upon whether the infringing is for **commercial or private
> financial gain**, with the latter punishment being far milder.

I would be very thankful if you could please explain the difference between commercial and private financial gain. (Google returns some super-formal documents, but could you please explain in casual language if possible?)

I feel like a private financial gain is when I'm, say, selling apples on the street, while a commercial financial gain is when I've opened a company, hired people, and we sell tons of apples daily. Am I right?

Many thanks and have a lovely day everybody!

Comment: I think the IELTS page is confused on the terminology used in law.  If you read https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/506 The requirement for criminal copyright is "commercial advantage or financial gain".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is reasonable, but I'd say if you were selling on the street that is a business, and so commercial.  Private financial gain is when (for example) You profit in some way, not your business.  Eg If I make a copy of a CD give it to my friend, on the expectation that he will make a copy of his in return, that is a "financial gain".

> The term “financial gain” includes receipt, or expectation of receipt, of anything of value, including the receipt of other copyrighted works.

However I think that the IELTS writer isn't a lawyer, since what the US criminal law says is subtly different.

> Any person who willfully infringes a copyright shall be punished ... if the infringement was committed for purposes of commercial advantage or private financial gain;

Then a separate section of law describes the punishments, which depend on the total number and total value of the copyright works, and not on any difference between commercial and private financial gain.

So you are right to be confused! Because the IELTS writer is confused too.